# syntax error when trying to generate devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, syntax-error

I recently added the devise gem to my rails application and the bundle install went smoothly. When I ran "rails generate devise:install" it generated a list of changes I should make to various files, which I incorporated.

I next ran `rails generate devise User` and received the following error message:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/ac
tive_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': C:/code/omrails/config/environmen
ts/development.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end (Synt
axError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/engine.rb:571:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from C:/code/omrails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-
3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.1
3/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I've looked in the referenced files, but can't really figure out what needs to be fixed.

Comment: You should check C:/code/omrails/config/environments/development.rb Line:41.

Comment: Got it! Thank you! I had two 'end's in my development file. Too long staring at the screen . . .

Answer (score 1):

Your config/environments/development.rb:41 has a msising "end" tag. If you are using git or something, try a diff to find the problem. If you can't find, paste your file here for inspection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was stumped with this problem, but your answer led me to review my development.rb file where I found the error (in my case a missing "}").